# Nested For loop in python?

Tags: python

```
def validateName(name):
    continueP = "Yes"
    alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

    while continueP=="Yes":
        for alphaCheck in alpha:
            letter = alphaCheck
            for a in name:
                if  a != letter:
                    print("Please enter a valid name")
        print("You have entered a valid name")
        continueP = input("Do you want to continue, input Yes to continue, input No to Exit: ")
        name = input("Please input a valid name, a valid name is only with characters A-Z: ")

name = input("Please input a valid name, a valid name is only with characters A-Z: ") 
validateName(name)
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is evaluate each character in my list to each character in a string someone would input. If a character that's not suppose to be in there is found it's suppose to tell me so. I'm pretty new to python so please keep that in mind. What follows is consecutive "Please enter a valid name" outputs. But if you evaluate a string like "Name" you can clearly see that the characters in that string match the characters in my list. Am I overlooking something? Because It looks like it should work to me. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

I don't understand why this isn't a valid question? I demonstrated what I tried and what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: What you suppose to do ?
if i write "name", so it will show up `you have entered a valid name` 4 times ?
if i write "na2g", so it will show up `valid` 3 times and `invalid` 1 times ?

Comment: It didn't do that, what it does is it prints out "Please enter a valid number" for each character in my list. I'm trying to compare each character in my list to each character in what the user inputs and see if it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in your code:

1. Use raw_input() instead of input() for user input. As input() will execute eval(raw_input())
2. When using a while loop like `while continueP == "Yes":` The `continueP` variable will actually only be validated at the beginning of the loop. Thus I would prefer `while True:` with a `break` statement for better control.
3. The order of validating/reprompt in the while loop is messed up

This works for me:

```
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

def validateName(name):

    while True:
        if [i for i in name if i not in alpha]:
            continueP = raw_input("Do you want to continue, input Yes to continue, input No to Exit: ")
            if not continueP == "Yes":
                exit(1)
            else:
                name = raw_input("Please input a valid name, a valid name is only with characters A-Z: ")
                continue
        break
    print("You have entered a valid name")

name = raw_input("Please input a valid name, a valid name is only with characters A-Z: ") 
validateName(name)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help but can you please tell me what's wrong in my code? I can't use any build-in functions, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, Can you please help me?

Comment: how do you mean, you can't use any build-in functions?

Comment: I can't use regex. I can only use basic things like loops, list, string functions. Pretty much I can't use **any** 'import' statements in my code. Everything else is allowed, but im having trouble with this, as far as I know everything should work like i described but it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, but what's wrong with my `For loops`? Why aren't they validating each character like I want them to?

Comment: Changed my answer according to your request to not use any import statements or rather ONLY build-in functions. Would have been good if you would have mentioned this in your question.